# This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, dataset

I have three nested tables in a dataset. I display the data based on the language ID, ie: EN is 1 FR is 2 and NL is 3. French and english exist in the database but Dutch does not exist yet and when the user selects NL I get the following error:

> This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding
>   parent values.

Below is the code that I use to get the data. The error happens when I try to create relations in the dataset.

```
 (ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("Cat_SubCat", dk1, dk2));
```

Now my question is, how can I check if the value exists in the dataset or database with the given code below?

```
 public static DataTable GetData(Int32 languageID)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string commandText = @"SELECT * FROM AlacarteCat where languageID = @ID;
                               SELECT * FROM AlacarteSubCat where languageID = @ID;
                               SELECT * from AlacarteItems where languageID = @ID";

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Common.GetConnectionString("SQLConnectionString")))
        {
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, myConnection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = languageID;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = command;
            da.TableMappings.Add("AlacarteCat", "AlacarteCat"); // table 0
            da.TableMappings.Add("AlacarteSubCat", "AlacarteSubCat"); // table 1
            da.TableMappings.Add("AlacarteItems", "AlacarteItems"); // table 2
            da.Fill(ds, "AlacarteCat");

            DataColumn dk1 = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ID"];
            DataColumn dk2 = ds.Tables[1].Columns["AlacarteCatID"];
            DataColumn dk3 = ds.Tables[1].Columns["ID"];
            DataColumn dk4 = ds.Tables[2].Columns["AlacarteSubCatID"];
            DataColumn dk5 = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"];
            DataColumn dk6 = ds.Tables[2].Columns["AlacarteCatID"];
            ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("Cat_SubCat", dk1, dk2));
            ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("SubCat_Items", dk3, dk4));
            ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("Cat_Items", dk5, dk6));

            if ((ds != null))
            {
                return ds.Tables["AlacarteCat"];
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 16):

By default, when you create a relationship, it enforces foreign key constraints, by setting to false, you are telling it that you dont want to enforce the relationship.

`ds1.DataRelation.Add(“relCustOrder”, parentCol, childCol, false)`

The solutions is to set constraint in DataRelation class to false

Answer (score -1):

use the subquery in select statements to control the related rows.
It is gonnna work.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my issue by adding a missing table entry. I use to build menu tree from sql server table.

You too must be missing an entry in table

some childCol is getting NULL